# Visual Studio Workflow REST API Call

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to get a user's property using a REST call in a Visual Studio workflow.

**The rest call:**

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountname='i:0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cfirs.last@sharepoint.com',propertyName='Manager')
```

This works if I simply append it to an URL and returns

**The return:**

```
<d:GetUserProfilePropertyFor xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">i:0#.f|membership|first.last@sharepoint.com</d:GetUserProfilePropertyFor>
```

Now I tried this simple workflow...

**Workflow:**
[image: Workflow]

...but it won't return the expected value, it's just returning a blank value.
My best guess is that my path is wrong, and I should be calling something like d/GetUserPropertyFor/0 or some index?

## Update

I got it to work. I messed with the app permissions as well as the API string I was using and all is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify Authorization="" for your RequestHeaders.

You could log the response code to debug the error.

[image]

My result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I logged the fix you provided with the headers but I'm getting a {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by granting full acess to Workflow service account at Webapplication level (Webapplicaiton --> User Policy).

As well as below request headers.

Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

Content-Type: "application/json;odata=verbose"

Authorization: ""